# I want to extract columns from a single message column sql query

Tags: sql

I have a logs message that I have to extract columns from with a sql query,
this how the message looks like:

> "device=EOHCS-ZA-JIS-FW severity=high from=EOHCloudFAZ(FL1KVM0000005594) trigger=Syslog Critical System Alerts log="logver=54 itime=1528457940 devid=FG1K5D3I13800425 devname=FWJIS01 vd=95_LHC date=2018-06-08 time=13:34:55 logid=0100044546 type=event subtype=system level=information logdesc="Attribute configured" user="JoshuaK" ui="ha_daemon" action=Edit cfgtid=701760128 cfgpath="system.settings" cfgattr="gui-allow-unnamed-policy[disable->enable]" msg="Edit system.settings """

can someone give me an idea

Comment: You missed a couple of databases such as `oracle`, `postgresql` etc

Comment: @user2542176 . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag your questions only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I can't think of a way to parse this reliably (regardless of the actual DBMS product being used) as the values are not quoted consistently e.g. the value for `trigger` contains spaces but is not enclosed in double quotes. The  value for `log=` is missing the closing double quote. Then there are some "keys" where the values aren't quoted at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for SQL-Server, you could use PATINDEX and extract the log message.

Below is the code to extract from value

```
declare @input nVarchar(max),@from nVarchar(MAX)
declare @FromStart int,@FromEnd int

set @input='device=EOHCS-ZA-JIS-FW severity=high from=EOHCloudFAZ(FL1KVM0000005594) trigger=Syslog Critical System Alerts log="logver=54 itime=1528457940 devid=FG1K5D3I13800425 devname=FWJIS01 vd=95_LHC date=2018-06-08 time=13:34:55 logid=0100044546 type=event subtype=system level=information logdesc="Attribute configured" user="JoshuaK" ui="ha_daemon" action=Edit cfgtid=701760128 cfgpath="system.settings" cfgattr="gui-allow-unnamed-policy[disable->enable]" msg="Edit system.settings';

SET @FromStart=PATINDEX('%from=%',@input)+5;
SET @FromEnd=PATINDEX('% trigger=%',@input)-@FromStart;
SELECT @from=SUBSTRING(@input,@FromStart,@FromEnd)
SELECT @from
```

Note : use equivalent of PATINDEX for your corresponding DB server. Also note that this works only if the input string have parameters in a defined order.